# Run dart code when a template's contents are instantiated

Tags: dart, dart-webui

`bar` is `@observable`.  When its value changes, new spans are instantiated.

```
<template iterate="foo in bar">
   <span>{{foo}}</span>
</template>
```

Is it possible to run dart code right after new spans are created?  I tried to run the code right after changing the value of `bar`, but at that moment the template still contains old spans.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the timer to schedule the code to run instead of running the code directly seems to solve my problem.

```
bar = newValue;
Timer.run(() {
  // run code here
});
```

The callback seems to be called after new spans are instantiated.